# "aura:if" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

Hi I am getting this error "aura:if" must not contain the '<' character
Is there any other way to redefine this.

**Cmp**

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.page < v.pages}">
           <ui:button aura:id="nextbtn" press="{!c.nextPage}" label="Next Page"/>
        </aura:if>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try the below. this will check if v.page is less than v.pages

```
 <aura:if isTrue="{!lessthan(v.page,v.pages)}">
```

documentation link :
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm

Comment: You can also use `lt` instead of `lessthan`, if you prefer.

Comment: Cool good to know @sfdcfox